# Threading with GPIO and Push Buttons

Tags: python, pi-3b+, rpi.gpio

I'm trying to loop some code in the main function of the program, while running a thread in the background that's listening for a button press through GPIO. I can see that the thread is running, however the button presses aren't being registered. It works as two separate programs however doesn't seem to be working when combined.

```
    from threading import Thread
    import time
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

    button1 = GPIO.input(23)
    button2 = GPIO.input(24)

    def buttonFunc():
        print("Button thread started.")
        time.sleep(2)

    while True:
        print("Button thread running...")
        time.sleep(1)

        if button1 == False:
            print("Button 1 pressed!!!")

        if button2 == False:
            print("Button 2 pressed!!!")

    Thread(target = buttonFunc).start()

    while True:
        print("Main program running.")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is your ‘while true: print(‘button thread...’ supposed to be inside the buttonfunc? If so you need to indent that loop by 1 tab.

Comment: This is a general programming question not belonging to Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com/